# Why doesn't my custom OutboundPathProcessorInterface work anymore?

Tags: 8

I wrote my own implementation of `OutboundPathProcessorInterface` to rewrite the URL of nodes to use the content of their field_project_url field.

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor;

use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;
use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor;
use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\InboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\OutboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MymoduleFieldRedirectPathProcessor implements OutboundPathProcessorInterface {

  public function processOutbound($path, &$options = array(), Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {

    if (isset($options['entity']) && is_object($options['entity']) && method_exists($options['entity'], 'hasField')) {
      $node = $options['entity'];

      if ($node->hasField('field_project_url') && !$node->field_project_url->isEmpty()) {
        $project_url = $node->field_project_url->getValue();

        if (preg_match("/^\/node\/[0-9]+\/(edit|translate|delete|translations)$/i", $path)) {
          // dont alter operational paths
        }
        else {
          $path = $project_url[0]['uri'];

          dpm($project_url[0]['uri']); // 'http://url.com'

          $options['absolute'] = TRUE;
          $options['external'] = TRUE;
          $options['base_url'] = null;
          $options['prefix'] = null;
        }

        if ($bubbleable_metadata) {
          $bubbleable_metadata->addCacheableDependency($node);
        }
      }
    }
    return $path;
  }

}
```

The teaser of that view has a title, an image linked to the content, and smart trimmed version of the body field, also linking to the content.

The value is appended, giving (for example) http://localhost:8888/myprojecthttp%3A//url.com.

This used to work, but I can't even get this right with older Drupal 8 versions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure setting `$options['external']` would work. `processOutbound()` should not be expected to redirect to external sites.

Comment: thats the clue i got from the drupal forums in the first place. this used to work though. is there any better way except for redirects?

Comment: Just to understand, what are users allowed to enter in that field? What is its purpose? If the purpose is allowing users to create a repository of links, I would rather create a field that is shown as a clickable URL.

Comment: that field is a link field, so users can enter a url. when set, the node's url should be that url. i dont like redirects because actually its another unnecessary server request so setting the node actual url to that field url seemed legit

Comment: Supposing it would work as you expect, it would a kind of redirect, without using HTTP headers. I don't see much difference. Also, the problem with that is that nodes would not be going to be easily editable, since normally first a user visits  node/1 and then clicks on the _Edit_ tab there. If you implement it as you describe, users should enter the path to edit a node directly on the browser URL bar.

Comment: they can edit from the contextual links in teasers or the content overview page, still. but thats really not the point... i dont understand how that would be a redirect still? when the url of the node is external?

Answer (score 0):

That's the right code of the **processOutbound** method

```
  public function processOutbound($path, &$options = array(), Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {

if (isset($options['entity']) && is_object($options['entity']) && method_exists($options['entity'], 'hasField')) {
  $node = $options['entity'];

  if ($node->hasField('field_project_url') && !$node->field_project_url->isEmpty()) {
    $project_url = $node->field_project_url->getValue();

    if (preg_match("/^\/node\/[0-9]+\/(edit|translate|delete|translations)$/i", $path)) {
      // dont alter operational paths
    }
    else {
      $path = ''; //Don't use $path variable at all

      dpm($project_url[0]['uri']); // 'http://url.com'
      $options['base_url'] = $project_url[0]['uri']; //Add your url as base_url

    }

    if ($bubbleable_metadata) {
      $bubbleable_metadata->addCacheableDependency($node);
    }
  }
}
return $path;
```

}